# Change EOL Character in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I’m sorry if this is a trivial question for you.

Is there any way to change the End of Line Character (EOL) character in Visual Studio 2010? I want to change it from Windows (‘\r\n’) format to UNIX (‘\n’) format.

Thanks

Comment: When saving a single file or globally?

Comment: I was guessing you meant *single file* when I started writing the answer. I was wrong. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. `File` / `Save As ...`
2. `Save with Encoding...` (press the arrow next to the `Save` button to see this option)
3. Choose appropriate EOL character from the `Line endings` drop-down list

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Click somewhere in the code page. Go to File -> Advanced Save Options -> use the Line Endings Drop box to select the line ending you want on ALL of your output files (when using \n for EOL). This solution is written for Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2):

For doing this globally, [Strip'em](http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php) is an add-in for Visual Studio that will automatically convert the line-ending when saving a file.  Works for VS 2008/2010/2012.